# OAuth consent screen not showing permissions

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I have a google login in my app when I try to click on sign in with google I do not see the permission it needs to access
My app uses users contacts and so I have added it to scope in consent screen settings but it do not show any permission. Can someone help me if there is anything else that needs to be configured as I need to verify my app from google

I want permission to display like this(sample image)

[image]
Scopes that I am using

[image]
this is the api
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the access token returned?  Profile is an open id connect scope its not an Oauth2 scope and there for not normally included in the list of requested permissions from the user.  Please edit your question and include your code rather pictures of code.  Also screen shots of the auth screen is great but taking a picture of the monitor? there are better ways.

Comment: @DaImTo hey sorry about the image... I have attached the screenshot. Also can you help me with what code exactly you want to see? Bwt login is working fine for me, its just the screen that is not showing the permission due to which I cannot verify my app

Comment: You cant control what google shows on the consent screen.   If its working then theres no problem.

Comment: But it should show a permission to access contacts right ? As I have configured to access it ?

Comment: I am using hello.js lib for google and facebook auth ? I just saw we need to add scope in it as well ... Tried that but didn't worked for me

Comment: As long as you get an access token back and can request your data properly your doing fine.

Comment: I notice a "warning" triangle next to the `/auth/contacts` scope. Can you hover over that warning and update your question with what it says? (Listing the text of the scopes would also help us, rather than posting a screen shot of those scopes.)

Comment: @Prisoner i think the warning is normally when you are requesting scopes that dont actually exist.   i dont recognize these ../auth ones as Google scopes.

Comment: Hey @Prisoner I have updated the screenshot

Comment: @DaImTo it says it will be restricted until approval

Comment: @rishabhagarwal all applications are restricted until approval everything has to go though the verification process.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use the [Google Oauth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to test a little.

## test 1 requesting authorization to Oauth2 scopes.

I am going to select Google contacts really there is not much point in selecting this one using google People api is a much better choice.

[image]

And everything under Google People API

[image]

This is the consent screen shown me

[image]

## test two authenticating with open id connect

I am going to only request

[image]

Now profile and email are special they are related to Open Id connect, which is out side of the Oauth2 because of that i was not actually shown a consent screen.  Because i am Authenticating to Google that this is me logging in.

I am not Authorizing any Oauth2 scopes because none were really requested.   Now this make confuse you because by requesting profile you are automatically given access to the users profile data which means that you can access the Google people api and do people/me and get the information about the person.

## conclusion

Only Oauth2 scopes appear to the user requesting access. not open id scopes.